# Significance of relationship of B occuring when A is true

Tags: statistical-significance, spss

Is there a statistical-significance measure  of B occurring when only cases of A being true?
I understand that to get a correlation you need two variables, but we are only looking at patients with A disease, but have the B symptoms. With the data set I have, can I say something how its likely to get symptom B if you had disease A?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a bit vague, but I will do my best to interpret it as it stands.  If your question is best summarized by your last statement, that is about making probability statements regarding symptoms provided disease status, then the answer is yes you absolutely can do this.  If my memory serves me, this is best done via a case control scheme.

The simplest example is a binary disease status and a binary exposure.  Case controls begin by sampling cases and controls (hence the name) irrespective of exposure status.  We can then create a contingency table for the data which may look like

```
       D    Not D
____________________
    E|  A      B
Not E|  C      D
```

You can then estimate the probability of exposure given disease status $P(E\vert D)$ from this table using contingency table methods. To do this however, you need to have patients which both do and do not have the diease.